# Unable to import pyodbc for Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyodbc

I've searched about every post I can find and tried everything to try and get my pip install of pyodbc to be recognized by python and I'm not having any luck.

I am a Python beginner, I am just trying to get my hands dirty by automating some NETEZZA SQL reports. So very basic just running out of IDLE Shell 3.9.2:

```
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyodbc: The specified module could not be found.
```

when I type help("modules") I do see pyodbc in the list:

_symtable           fractions           **pyodbc**              weakref

I run a python -m pip list to make sure it sees pyodbc as well:

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE8xW.png)

Pip install gives me "requirement already satisfied:" - it does mention something about urllib3 in case that's relevant:

[pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOJxw.png)

lastly I made sure the working directory in IDLE was the same these pip installs are going to:

> os.getcwd()

> 'C:\ProgramData\App-V\4FF67385-8232-4086-95ED-EE994D0333F1\3DB7CB53-C828-47BC-89E4-9D8616F473B0\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python3.9.2'

I have no idea where to go next, or other things to look into. Everything I find it seems like it should be working

Comment: When you first launch IDLE does the banner include "[MSC v.19xx 64 bit (AMD64)]" ?

Comment: yes - "Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32"

Comment: This looks like it might be related to [GitHub 663](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663). You could try installing the corresponding wheel file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc) to see if it works any better.

Comment: Since i'm a beginner and have never done anything outside of pip install - what would I do with the wheel file exactly? I see this referenced " pyodbc-4.0.30-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (67 kB)" in IDLE, would me grabbing that same one from the site be doing anything different?

Comment: You would download that wheel file and then do `pip install C:\path\to\pyodbc-4.0.30-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`. It will be the same version of pyodbc but perhaps Christoph compiled it with slightly different settings than Michael (Kleehammer) did.

Comment: Hmm, I just did a clean install of 64-bit Python 3.9.4 on a Windows 8 VM. `pip install pyodbc` worked fine and `import pyodbc` does not produce an error.

Comment: tried that other wheel file and same deal. Says it installed successfully, shows up in pip list ... import error module not found. I feel like i'm taking crazy pills

Answer (score 3):

FYI to anyone who finds this in the future, it was citrix virtual desktop related issues for my work log-in.

Not an actual Python issue that was preventing it from working.

Comment: Hi Skriv, could you elaborate?